# Garbage value getting produced in textView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, garbage-collection

I have two activities : lets say **A** and **B**

**A** has a button which opens **B** using `intent` concept.

Through **B** I am saving data in **database** using `SQLite` concept.

**A** is the main activity which has a `textView` which is showing some value !

code:

Using `SharedPreferences` to store int value and display in MainActivity **A**

```
c=sp.getInt(Salaryflag, 0);
         str=Integer.toString(c);

        tv.setText(str);
```

Now I am using some algorithm to calculate `sum()` in one **row** in the database a store its value in an **int** variable

Now in `onResume` I am using this concept to change the value of the **A** `textView` ! :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onResume();
        ItemsDataBase xyx=new ItemsDataBase(this);
        xyx.open();
        int lola;
        lola=xyx.getSum();

        xyx.close();
        c=c-lola;
         str=Integer.toString(c);
        tv.setText(str);

    }
```

Now what I want is that when I go back from second Acitvity **B** to **A** it should immediately show the changes.

But actually It is showing some garbage value and when I restart the app after closing then it shows the desired changes in the `textView`

How to remove this logical error ?

Garbage value:

[image: Garbage value in textview]

After closing the app and reopening it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write c=sp.getInt(Salaryflag, 0); in your on resume too as you are assigning c-lola to c.

When you are restarting the activity, line  c=sp.getInt(Salaryflag, 0) is getting executed first so it displaying perfactly.

When you coming from B to A , the onResume() of A gets called so you have to initialize/assign variable c in onResume() as well.

Comment: let me try it frst !